# Polygon: Metamask is not sending Matic to different wallets

Tags: metamask, polygon

I was trying to transfer Mumbai testnet Matic between my wallets. But after I clicked send, put the amount and gas, and proceeded to send, there was no record created, and the Matics were not transferred.

Strangely, it sometimes works but most of the time doesn't.

Has anyone encountered problems similar to this? The same thing never happens on Eth and Eth Georil btw.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the transaction is still being processed and has not yet been included in a block. You can check the status of the transaction on a block explorer to see if it is still pending or if it has failed.

It is also possible that there was an error with the transaction, such as an incorrect gas amount or an error with the contract being called. In this case, you may need to debug the transaction to determine the cause of the issue.

Additionally, it is worth checking if there are any network issues or congestion on the Mumbai testnet that could be causing delays or failures in your transactions.

Comment: If it is still being processed, it should be in the transaction list of that wallet. But it doesn't even show up there. My transaction list is not updated with any new records.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Try to use a different RPC from this list: https://chainlist.org/. Polygon testnet official RPC is not the most stable one, from experience.